# Update only one column in user info - MySQL NodeJS

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'm building a classic CRUD (create, read, update, delete) API with NodeJS/Express and MySQL.
I created a route to update my user information that works fine.

**The problem :**
If I don't send EVERY data (`first_name`, `last_name` etc...), the columns with no data update to `undefined` in MySQL database, and the column with data don't update. I would like that if I don't send data, no change happens for the columns, and only the one with data change.

Here is my controller :

```
module.exports.updateUser = (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.method == "PUT") {
        let userDetails = `UPDATE users SET first_name = '${req.body.first_name}', last_name = '${req.body.last_name}', user_name = '${req.body.user_name}' WHERE id = ${req.params.id}`;

        sql.query(userDetails, function (err, result) {
            if (!err) {
                res.status(200).json({ message: "User infos updated." })
            } else {
                res.status(401).json({ message: "Error when updating user infos." })
            }
        })
    }
}
```

So, if I make a `PUT` request on an existing user in the database with only the mail for example:

```
{
   "mail": "test2@example.com"
}
```

all my user data become `null` and `user.mail` stays the same.

Anyone could help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this query for update one or more filled update at a time

```
module.exports.updateUser = (req, res, next) => {
        if (req.method == "PUT") {
            let query = '';
            if(req.body.first_name){
               query = `first_name = 
                '${req.body.first_name}'`
            }else
            if(req.body.last_name){
               query = ` last_name = 
                '${req.body.last_name}'`
            }else
            if(req.body.user_name){
               query = `user_name = 
               '${req.body.user_name}'`
            }eles if(req.body.first_name 
                    && req.body.last_name) 
                  {
                    query =`first_name = '${req.body.first_name}',  last_name =    '${req.body.last_name}'`
                  }else if( 
                     req.body.last_name &&  req.body.user_name 
                  {
                    query = `last_name =  '${req.body.last_name}', user_name =   '${req.body.user_name}'`
                  }else if(req.body.first_name
                    && req.body.last_name && req.body.user_name) 
                  {
                    query =`first_name = '${req.body.first_name}', last_name =   '${req.body.last_name, user_name =       '${req.body.user_name}'}'`
                  }
            let userDetails = `UPDATE users SET ${query} WHERE id = ${req.params.id}`;
    
            sql.query(userDetails, function (err, result) {
                if (!err) {
                    res.status(200).json({ message: "User infos updated." })
                } else {
                    res.status(401).json({ message: "Error when updating user infos." })
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

Comment: so what you saying is, i have to check each field before creating a query is that right?

Comment: yes, before creating a query you check each field

Comment: that could work, but im using https://www.npmjs.com/package/flexqp flexqp package so we can update only requested field, have a try

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @jutendra, it works.
After few months (and gained skills), here is a cleaner version if ever someone is interested :

```
module.exports.updateUser = (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.method !== "PUT") return;

  const updates = [];
  if (req.body.first_name) updates.push(`first_name = '${req.body.first_name}'`);
  if (req.body.last_name) updates.push(`last_name = '${req.body.last_name}'`);
  if (req.body.user_name) updates.push(`user_name = '${req.body.user_name}'`);

  if (updates.length === 0) {
    res.status(400).json({ message: "No updates provided" });
    return;
  }

  const query = `UPDATE users SET ${updates.join(", ")} WHERE id = ${req.params.id}`;
  sql.query(query, (err, result) => {
    if (!err) {
      res.status(200).json({ message: "User infos updated." });
    } else {
      res.status(401).json({ message: "Error when updating user infos." });
    }
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//change parameteres accordingly
app.patch('/employee/edit/:id', (req,res) => {
const updates = [];
const id = req.params.id;

if (req.body.name) updates.push(`name = '${req.body.name}'`);
if (req.body.profession) updates.push(`profession = 
'${req.body.profession}'`);
if (req.body.email) updates.push(`email = '${req.body.email}'`);

if (updates.length === 0) {
    res.status(400).json({ message: "No updates provided" });
    return;
  }

const query = `UPDATE employee SET ${updates.join(", ")} WHERE id = 
${id}`;
pool.query(query,id, (err, result) => {
if (!err) {
    console.log(query);
  res.status(200).json({ message: "employee infos updated." });
} else {
    res.send(err,'error')
  res.status(401).json({ message: "Error when updating employee infos." 
});
}
});
});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).